# MKStoreKit 101: getting a basic delegate example

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I wanted to get some 101 help with using MKStoreKit, for Objective-C. In particular I am trying to get the delegate to work and respond, so that I can get things like list of product objects and descriptions. I have tried assigning delegate in my class but can't get it to respond to some of the optional delegate methods.

If someone has a sample implementation it would be great.

Comment: Are you sure you've declared the delegate methods properly? A common problem with delegate methods is that sometimes there are typos in your declaration, and the messages don't get sent.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (just using the AppDelegate for now):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];    

    [MKStoreManager sharedManager];

    [MKStoreManager setDelegate:self];  

    [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] purchasableObjects];

    return YES;
}
```

Which calls back (in my AppDelegate):

```
- (void)productFetchComplete {

    NSArray *products = [MKStoreManager sharedManager].purchasableObjects;

    NSLog(@"productFetchComplete: %@", products);
}
```

Perhaps you can show us what you are doing if this isn't working for you.